# How to add parameter to header request?

Tags: javascript, api, http-headers

I have this header :

```
var header = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'x-application-id':applicationId,
        'hashing': this.hashGenerator(location),
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
```

also I have some condition like this :

```
if(this.props.token != null){
        header.access-token=this.props.token
}
```

but it seems I can't do like this to add a parameter

> header.access-token

any idea to solve this ?
Thanks beforehands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: `res.headers['access-token'] = this.props.token`

and also, for custom headers you might need to add a "x-" prefix

see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp for more about object properties in JS

Answer (score 0):

instead of      **header.access-token=this.props.token**

you can simply use json format as below

headers: {'Authorization': '[API key]'},